# Error after executing command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying to make a minigame and I need custom npc's
I need them to have a name, trades and infinite trades(they never run out).

Here is the command I have been using:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~3 ~ {Profession:3,Career:1,CarrierLevel:100{Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:"minecraft:iron_ingot",Count:5},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1}},{buy:{id:"minecraft:barrier",Count:1},sell:{id:"minecraft:barrier",Count:1}}]},CustomName:"John Smith",CustomNameVisible:100
```

but it says:

```
[14:12:38] Data tag parsing failed: Expected '}' but got '{' at: ...ession:3,Career:1,CarrierLevel:100{<--[HERE]
```

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The error points to the problem:

```
CarrierLevel:100{Offers:{Recipes:
```

There should be a comma between CarrierLevel and Offers.  There should not be a curly bracket before Offers.  In the command you posted, you were also missing a closing curly bracket at the end of the command.

Here is the fixed command:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~3 ~ {Profession:3,Career:1,CarrierLevel:100,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:"minecraft:iron_ingot",Count:5},maxUses:9999999,sell:{id:"gold_ingot",Count:1}},{buy:{id:"minecraft:barrier",Count:1},sell:{id:"minecraft:barrier",Count:1}}]},CustomName:"John Smith",CustomNameVisible:100}
```

Here he is:
[image: John Smith]